# What is the font with points in the middle of the letters called?

Tags: product-recommendation, books-generally, writing-printing

What is this [type of] font called - the kind that makes it look like every leg of every letter is a snake that swallowed a block?

Where can I download such a font?

[image: Title page of "Sefer Mekor Chayim," by R' Meir Chayim Ungar, printed in Jerusalem in 5720]

Comment: Similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31542

Comment: I don't think this is on topic.

Comment: |product-recommendation|?

Comment: I'm not on board with closing this.  It's useful to Jews writing about Jewish learning. It's on the bubble, for sure, but it's relevant to Jewish life in that way.

Comment: This doesn't seem so different from [this](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/44455/academic-abbreviations) open question (which I had argued for closing, but the community disagreed).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's called Stam, and was designed by [Francesca Baruch](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%A0%D7%A6%27%D7%A1%D7%A7%D7%94_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A) in the 1930s (originally for the logo of the newspaper Haaretz - this logo is still in use).

Not to be confused with more recent fonts also bearing the name Stam, which are made to look like Ashkenazic or Sephardic Torah lettering, complete with crowns on the letters.

I see where Davka has repackaged it under the name Davka Simcha. They offer it as part of a [25-font package](http://www.davka.com/cgi-bin/product.cgi?product=549) for about $50.