# Can someone identify this font?

Tags: jewish-books, writing-printing

This font is commonly used in seforim published by [Kehot Publication Society](https://www.kehot.org/). I've seen it used in other places as well, but I've been unable to identify it. I really don't think it's a custom font....

So I'm hoping that someone can identify the font for the words "Likutei Torah". Thanks!

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem on topic.

Comment: Have you tried calling Kehot? I once wanted to know the name of the font used in a certain ArtScroll book, so called ArtScroll, asked for Sheah Brander (listed as the art designer, or some such, of that book), and asked him. He remembered without having to check.

Comment: Very similar: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5879.

Comment: Those fonts from Davka do bear a strong resemblance.

Comment: I meant that the question, not the font, is similar.

Answer (score 1):

According to a couple of graphic designers in a graphic design group I'm in, the font is called קהת and was likely custom-made for the Kehot company (hence the name), and as such, probably isn't available anywhere else. See [here](https://www.prog.co.il/threads/%D7%95%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%91-%D7%A2%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%94-%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A6%D7%99%D7%90%D7%AA-%D7%A4%D7%95%D7%A0%D7%98.102577/) and [here](http://old2.ih.chabad.info/forums/theforum_he/viewtopic.php?p=23713&sid=f96b1cc8e1d6906fac80962f861e5dd3) for short discussions of Chabad fonts.

Note: A few font designers have made similar fonts. For example, Tamir Pomerantz made פורמלין (see [here](http://f.tamirp.com/), scroll left):

[image]

The Lamed isn't the same, but the "legs" of the letters are similar (comp. to [this](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/16069)).