# Academic abbreviations

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, acronyms

Academic texts typically use acronyms to refer to books in Tana"ch, [Talmud](https://webapps.oru.edu/new_php/library/guides/talmudAbbrevIndxPrint.html), and rabbinic literature. I am presently working on editing the citations given within a translation to bring them more in line with academic standards. However, I have only been able to find abbreviations for [biblical books](http://hbl.gcc.edu/abbreviationsCHICAGO.htm) and sha"s. Is there any resource for academic abbreviations for other sefarim in Rabbinic literature?

Comment: To closure voters: This question is 100% explicitly about Judaism.

Comment: Thanks, @IsaacMoses, I was beginning to wonder whether I should re-ask on Academia.SE, rather than on Mi Yodeya

Comment: Related (and not closed): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7171/3

Comment: @IsaacMoses I cast the first close vote and am not sure why this is about Judaism.  If I ask for a list of fonts used by publishers who happen to be Jewish book publishers, would that be on topic?  This is a question which has to do with something Jewish, but so is a question about matzah ball recipes

Comment: @YEZ This is about study of Jewish texts. There is no more Jewish activity.

Comment: @IsaacMoses Are questions about where I could buy ink to print a sefer on topic?  Just trying to figure out the parameters here.

Comment: @YEZ, is there reason to believe that experts on Judaism would be more likely than the general population to be able to answer?

Comment: @IsaacMoses Yes.  How about questions about Jews, which is explicitly off-topic?  I think generally experts on Judaism happen to be more aware of that also.  Experts on Judaism aren't more likely to know this, or that, because of their expertise in Judaism, it's because of external details.

Comment: @YEZ, Questions about Jews that are not about Judaism are off-topic. Questions about Jews that are about Judaism are [on-topic](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Knowing how to cite Jewish sources is so strongly tied to expertise in Judaism that I have trouble understanding your position here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16416/discussion-between-yez-and-isaac-moses).

Comment: @YEZ Regarding your comparison to fonts.... [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/31542/5323) is open, and [this question](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/5879/5323) is closed..... (could not post to chat room; room was frozen 3 days ago)

Comment: @Shokhet http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17431359#17431359

Comment: @Shokhet wow. Those two look like they ought to have the same disposition, one way or the other.

Answer (score 2):

Try the preface of an academic-style book on Talmud. The better editions of the [Jastrow dictionary](http://www.tyndalearchive.com/TABS/Jastrow/) have an abbreviations page that I believe covers Talmud Bavli, Yerushlami, and Medrash including some names and lots of academic abbreviations other than titles.

Comment: There's an online edition of Jastrow [here](http://www.tyndalearchive.com/TABS/Jastrow/). English abbreviations begin on the second page of Abbreviations.

Comment: I've been using that online edition for years and never once bothered to look for the abbreviations page! Editing in now.

Comment: It didn't have many of the abbreviations I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! I have always found [קובץ ראשי תיבות וקיצורים](http://zbermanbooks.com/product-59103.html) and [אוצר ראשי תיבות](http://zbermanbooks.com/product-59207.html) (free older print [on HebrewBooks](http://hebrewbooks.org/34968)) to be *extremely* useful in breaking down roshei teivos that I did not understand.

Additionally, while I haven't used them at all (and therefore can't vouch for their reliability/usefulness), these websites ([1](http://www.kizur.co.il/home.php), [2](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/tohen.asp?id=9)) from a Google search may also be of use to you.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the luach roshei teivos in the back of the tanya. You'll find most of them there. Let me know if this helps

Comment: Rashei teivot work if I'm looking for the Hebrew forms, I'm looking for standard academic ones though.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt there are academics who write in Hebrew too

Comment: Yeah but they tend to have their own set of abbreviations.

Comment: @DoubleAA, I realise, however since I am editing the citations in a translation, it seems kind of backwards to use Hebrew r"t.

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt Oh. Then what language do you want to use?

Comment: @DoubleAA, as above, the translation is in English, so the citations should use Latin characters (like Deut. 6:4 for Devarim 6:4). See links in question

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt I believe that DoubleAA is hinting that you ought to edit the question so that readers know, without digging, that you specifically want English abbreviations.